# Custom op backward

Tags: mxnet

I am writing a custom op, and I got stucked when writing the backward part.

When I call *out_grad[0].asnumpy()* or do any manipulation of the out_grad, the program crash without any error message.

I tried fill the in_grad with zeros, the program run smoothly, but I need the grad to flow backward.

    `def backward(self, req, out_grad, in_data, out_data, in_grad, aux):
            self.assign(in_grad[0], req[0], 0)
            self.assign(in_grad[1], req[1], 0)`

What's going wrong here?

Comment: I use '.shape' to get the out_grad's shape, it turn out to be empty. Maybe something went wrong in the upstream. But how can I figure it out?

Comment: I have found what is going wrong, I have post my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

[Custom Operator in MXNet](http://mxnet.io/how_to/new_op.html#customop) show us how to define a loss function using custom op. The loss op is very special because it doesn't need grad to be flow into.

But in my situation, I need grad to flow into my op. So, the function below should return the dependency instead of empty as in loss op.

```
def declare_backward_dependency(self, out_grad, in_data, out_data):
    return [out_grad[0]]
```

In my opinion, the dependency is some variable which the gradient should be delievered to.

Comment: What do you mean by "grad to be flow into"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow the tutorial here for developing a
[Custom Operator in MXNet](http://mxnet.io/how_to/new_op.html#customop).

If that does not help, provide your full code of the Custom operator along with some sample data and a simple model with which this issue can be easily reproduced.

Comment: Yes. The tutorial show us how to define a loss function using custom op. The loss op is very special because it doesn't need grad to be flow into. I have found what is going wrong. I'm now posting my solution.